# executing **kill -9 <PID>** command through java is not working

Tags: java, linux

I am executing the below command to kill a process, but its not killing any process.

Command I tried: #kill -9 "2319"

But at the same time when I execute the same command in command prompt its working fine.

```
private void killProcess()
{
    InputStream errorStream = null;
    final String taskKill = isWindows() ? InstallerConstants.WIN_TASKKILL : InstallerConstants.LIN_TASKKILL;
    try 
    {
        Process process = null;
        final String killCMD = taskKill+"\""+getGuiProcess()+"\"";\\kill -9 "2319"
        process = runTime.exec(killCMD);
        errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
        bufferedReader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream));
        String error = "";
        while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null)
        {
            error =  bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        if(!(error==null || "".equals(error)))
        {
            logger.error(error);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ioException) {
        logger.error(ioException.getMessage(), ioException);
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            if(bufferedReader!=null)
            {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            if(errorStream!=null)
            {
                errorStream.close();
            }               
        } 
        catch (IOException ioException) {
            logger.error(ioException.getMessage(), ioException);
        }           
    }
}
```

Please help to overcome this problem.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the absolute path to the kill command?

Comment: does your getGuiProcess() return right values?

Comment: Yes, getGuiProcess() is returning right values.

Comment: @Axel.. I didn't specified the absolute path

Comment: @kgopi You have rights to run `kill -9`?

Comment: Yes, as a administrator I am running the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the absolute path  to the kill command

```
 /bin/kill may be? 

 $ whereis kill //output will show you where kill command is.
```

do you get any errors btw?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, bufferedReader.readLine(); is returning null when I execute the command

Comment: kill: /bin/kill /usr/bin/kill /usr/share/man/man1/kill.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/kill.1p.gz /usr/share/man/man3p/kill.3p.gz /usr/share/man/man2/kill.2.gz..............No, result through java code

Comment: @kgopi did you change this line : final String killCMD = taskKill+"\""+getGuiProcess()+"\"";\\kill -9 "2319" to use the absolute path? You had to edit this String actually: InstallerConstants.LIN_TASKKILL

Comment: what ever the solution you mentioned its not working, I followed like eg:-**runtime.exec("kill -9 1234", null, new File("/bin"));** if I do it through command prompt manually its working, through code its returning null.